# Layout buttons locked windows forms application visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: Locked:<]

I don't know why but my layout buttons are locked and I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: I wonder if they would enable if you select two controls at once instead of only one ? :)

Comment: Hahahaha ,my god I'm so stupid, thanks!